# How to convert C++ unsigned char* to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0

I have a method in C++ created for AES 256 Encryption which works:

```
void AES_Encrypt(unsigned char* message, unsigned char* expandedKey)
{
      unsigned char numOfRounds = 13;
      unsigned char* state = new unsigned char[16];

      AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey);
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfRounds; i++)
      {
          //bla bla
          AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey + (16 * (i + 1)));
      }

      // bla bla
      AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey + 224);
}
```

and

```
void AddRoundKey(unsigned char *state, unsigned char* roundKey)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] = state[i] ^ roundKey[i];
}
```

but when I translate it into C#:

```
private void AddRoundKey(byte[] state, byte[] roundKey)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] = (byte)(state[i] ^ roundKey[i]);
}
```

I get errors on the exact translated function:

```
AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey + (16 * (i + 1)));
AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey + 224);
```

How could I translate `void AddRoundKey(unsigned char *state, unsigned char* roundKey)` correctly in this case?

Comment: A char* (message)  is a byte[] array terminated with '\0'.  You are using fixed length of 16 bytes.  Is it always 16 bytes?  The message probably is different lengths  while the key is probably fixed length.

Comment: Yes, it is always 16. The initial error says, obviously, that I cannot use '+' on a byte[] and int (16*(i+1)). If I convert the int into a byte I get error for byte[] + byte.

Comment: The message is always 16 bytes and the key is always 240 bytes after expansion.

Comment: A byte is 0 to 255.  Will multiplying by 16 cause an over flow (shift left 4 bits)?  You are also adding 224 to the value so expandedKey must be less than 31 (255 - 224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way will be passing the offset:

```
void AddRoundKey(byte[] state, byte[] roundKey, int offset)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            state[i] = (byte)(state[i] ^ roundKey[i + offset]);
    }
```

then you call it:

```
        AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey, (16 * (i + 1)));
        ...
        AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey, 244);
```

Other

You can use [unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/chfa2zb8(v=vs.110)) keyword (notice to enable unsafe in your project settings)

```
unsafe void AddRoundKey(byte* state, byte* roundKey)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            state[i] = (byte)(state[i] ^ roundKey[i]);
    }
```

then use fixed when you call it:

```
fixed (byte* state_pointer = state, expandedKey_pointer = expandedKey)
        {
            AddRoundKey(state_pointer, expandedKey_pointer + 244);
        }
```

when *state* and *expandedKey* is byte[].

Comment: So simple. Thank you, Stefan!